# In Django what is the smarter way to dynamically load some JavaScript based on view name if exists?

Tags: javascript, django, view

Every time a call a view with a template, in Django, I want to load a JavaScript file with the same name if exists.

So, if I call the view `foo`, I want to load automatically `foo.js` in specific (public) dir if exists.

Abstract this in template is easy, assuming that I'll pass to the template a list of JavaScripts to load and loading it in a base template.

But how I can get this generic for each view without writing code in every view? With a context processor? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In class based views you can add a mixin to add class name to context. Or you can use middleware with `process_view` and put view's name somewhere in `request`

Comment: ok thanks i'll watch for the second option, because i'm not so advanced to use class based views now.. but the middleware seems a good way to go